# Execute a function forever with different time intervals in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a function in perpetuity. There are 3 time intervals say 5s, 10s, 15s and I want to execute say function myFunction() after these time intervals. setInterval() doesn't work as we can't update the time interval. Running the function in loop with set timeout is also not doing the required task(I have to fetch the time interval based on which of the 3 buttons i.e., 5s, 10s, 15s is active and I have to make the next button active in cycle: 5s->10s->15s... 5s->10s->15s in perpetuity).

```
var time = 0;
if(button5s) time = 5000
else if(button10s) time = 10000
else time = 15000.

while(true) 
execute myFunction() post time
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `setTimeout`. Just make sure you initialise it with a variable, and clear the timeout whenever a new button is clicked.

```js
// Cache the button container, and the buttons
const container = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// Add a listener to the container that can catch the
// events from its child elements (the buttons) as they
// bubble up the DOM. (See `event delegation` in the additional notes)
// Note that we're also immediately calling `handleClick`
// instead of assigning it to the listener
// because we want `handleClick` to return a new function that
// *will* act as the handler, and to scope the timer so that it
// is not global
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick());

// Initialises a timer, and returns a new function
// that will be used as the handler for the click listener
function handleClick() {

  let timer;
  
  // The function to be used as the handler - accepts
  // an event from the clicked element
  return function (e) {

    // First rule of Event Delegation Club - check
    // that the element that was clicked is the one
    // you're writing code for (a button)
    if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    
      // Clear the existing timer
      clearTimeout(timer);

      // Destructure the text content, and the `sec` data
      // attribute from the button
      const { textContent, dataset: { sec } } = e.target;

      // Remove the active classes from the buttons
      buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('active'));

      // Add an active class to the current button
      e.target.classList.add('active');

      // Loop! We log the current time, and then call loop again
      // with the value from the data attribute (times 1000)
      function loop() {
        console.log(`Timer set at ${textContent}`);
        timer = setTimeout(loop, +sec * 1000);
      }

      // Call `loop` for the first time
      loop();

    }
    
  }

}
```

```css
button { border-radius: 5px; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.active { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<section class="buttons">
  <button data-sec="5">5 secs</button>
  <button data-sec="10">10 secs</button>
  <button data-sec="15">15 secs</button>
</section>
```

Additional documentation

- [Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 0):

Run a `setTimeout` that calls itself again each time, but with a different `time` interval.

```js
let button5s = document.getElementById("button5s")
let button10s = document.getElementById("button10s")
let button15s = document.getElementById("button15s")

button5s.onclick = ()=>{time = 5000}
button10s.onclick = ()=>{time = 10000}
button15s.onclick = ()=>{time = 15000}


let time = 15000

advanceTime()

function advanceTime () {
  // RUN FUNCTION CODE HERE
  console.log("hello world!")

  setTimeout(advanceTime, time)
  
  if (time === 5000) time = 10000
  else if (time === 10000) time = 15000
  else time = 5000
}
```

```html
<button id="button5s">5s</button>
<button id="button10s">10s</button>
<button id="button15s">15s</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, JavaScript is SingleThreaded.

```
while(true)
```

would therefor block the main thread and results in none responding services. What you are most likely searching for is

```
setTimeout(function, timeout);
```

Edit:

This is an example to run this infinitely.

```
let timeoutId
const doStuff = () => {
  //do something
  timeoutId = setTimeout(doStuff, timeout);
}
```

and if you want to quit it:*

```
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

Comment: How would this achieve perpetuity?

Comment: you can call the function again. (see my edits)

Comment: `while (True)` would work fine as long as you have an `await` in the loop body, no need for multithreading